# I would like to know why the result of this exercise is "10x"

Tags: radicals

The resolution of this exercise $(2\sqrt{x})*(5\sqrt[3]{x})$ is **10x**. But I can't understand the steps to reach that result, since when I try to solve it, I get to:

- $(2\sqrt{x})\cdot(5\sqrt[3]{x})$
- $5 \cdot 2$
- $(\sqrt{x}) = x ^ \frac{1}{2}$ and $(\sqrt[3]{x}) = x ^ \frac{1}{3}$
- $x ^ \frac{1}{2} \cdot  x ^ \frac{1}{3} = x ^ \frac{5}{6}$
- $ 10x ^ \frac{5}{6} $

I would like to know how it is resolved

Comment: $10x$ is wrong.

Comment: Your solution is right.

Comment: I copied it here and it tells me that the result is 10x
https://es.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(2%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%5Cright)%5Ccdot%5Cleft(5%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D%5Cright)

Comment: Yes, as DonAntonio said you are right.

Comment: @LucasDamian It seems Symbolab is not parsing the cube root properly. https://es.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(2%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%5Cright)%5Ccdot%5Cleft(5x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%5Cright)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$10x^{1/2}\times x^{1/3}=10x^{1/2+1/3}=10x^{\frac{3+2}{6}}=10x^{5/6}$$